# Recuperación de nombre de usuario

Tags: google-apps-script

Estoy tratando de usar el servicio Google Apps Script para obtener el nombre de usuario del usuario que inició sesión en mi sitio de Google. Puedo hacer que el correo electrónico se muestre bien, pero no consigo la forma de que me devuelva solo el nombre.

```js
var loggedEmail = '';

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setEmail).getEmail();

function setEmail(data){
  loggedEmail = data;
  console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo es habilitando el servicio avanzado "People" y agregando el "scope" `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` en el manifiesto de tu proyecto (appsscript.json). La documentación (ver ligas abago) incluye las instrucciones específicas a seguir y un ejemplo de cómo obtener el nombre del usuario activo.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people